# Get url from webview Windows Universal

Tags: windows, webview, win-universal-app

I cannot get the correct url when i use webview in windows. The code i use:

```
  String host;
        String url;
        private void web_FrameContentLoading(WebView sender, WebViewContentLoadingEventArgs args)
        {
            if (host == args.Uri.Host)
            {

                url = host;
            }
        }

        private void web_NavigationCompleted(WebView sender, WebViewNavigationCompletedEventArgs args)
        {

            host = args.Uri.Host;
        }
```

and in xmal

```
  <WebView x:Name="web" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Source="https://m.youtube.com" FrameContentLoading="web_FrameContentLoading" NavigationCompleted="web_NavigationCompleted" />
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why you said you don't have the correct URL ? Your code looks fine so what is your problem ?
If you want the full URL, just use args.Uri (Host will return you the host name).